# Gravar no banco valores do ComboBox C# ao invés das descrições

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma tela em um form de cadastro simples, onde possui alguns combobox. Setei seus valores manualmente mesmo.

EX; Em um combo que irá cadastrar o perfil de acesso de um usuário, tenho nesse combo a opção 1- Limitado, 2 - total. Porém, como eu faço para hora que gravar no banco caso seja a opção 1 - Limitado ele persista com a sigla L e se for a opção 2 - Total ele persista com a sigla F na coluna de minha tabela?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para você ter o resultado esperado (numa implementação "melhor"), você precisa definir uma classe que represente um item em seu `comboBox`. Ex:

```
public class MeuComboBoxItem 
{
    public string TextoDoItem { get; set; }
    public object ValorDoItem { get; set; }

    string  public override string ToString()
    {
        return TextoDoItem;
    }
}
```

Populando o combo:

```
MeuComboBoxItem item = new MeuComboBoxItem();
item.TextoDoItem = "1- Limitado";
item.ValorDoItem = "L";

comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

Para resgatar o valor do item selecionado:

```
string valorDoItemSelectionado = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as MeuComboBoxItem).ValorDoItem.ToString();
```

---

Resposta baseada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source).

Comment: Pow cara, muito bom vou testar...era exatamente isso que eu precisava.Top.

Comment: Legal! Fico feliz por ter ajudado! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma lista e atribuir ela ao combobox.

```
public sealed class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Texto;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var itens = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
itens.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Valor = "1", Texto = "Ola" });
itens.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Valor = "2", Texto = "Oi" });

cbo.DataSource = itens;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Texto";
cbo.ValueMember = "Valor";
```

Resgatar valor selecionado:

```
var item = (ComboBoxItem)cbo.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma classe contendo o texto e o valor e atribuir para o comboBox. Exemplo:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
private void Test()
{
   ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
   item.Text = "Item text1";
   item.Value = 12;

   comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

   comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

   MessageBox.Show((comboBox1.SelectedItem as   ComboboxItem).Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Caio, obrigado pela resposta, ajudou demais...

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de se fazer isso é usando a propriedade DataSource do ComboBox, desta forma o Combobox já fica preparado para utilizar o DataBinding, sem contar que se o valor do campo de chave for de um tipo diferente de string, evita de ter de usar casts pelo código, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
// ***** Exemplo 1 - Utilizando uma List
// Neste exemplo utilizarei uma lista de KeyValuePar para identificar os meus itens.

var lstData = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(1, "Valor 1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(2, "Valor 2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(3, "Valor 3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(4, "Valor 4")
};

cboComboBox1.DataSource = null;
cboComboBox1.Items.Clear();
// Utilizo um BindingSource para "bindar os dados com os itens do Combobox"
cboComboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(lstData, null);
// Aqui fala qual será o campo a ser exibido
cboComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
// Aqui fala qual campo será selecionado
cboComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";


// ***** Exemplo 2 - Utilizando uma List de um objeto
// Neste exemplo utilizarei uma lista de KeyValuePar para identificar os meus itens.
class ObjetoTeste 
{
    public ObjetoTeste (int codigo, string descricao)
    {
        this.Codigo = codigo;
        this.Descricao = descricao;
    }

    public int Codigo { get; private set; } 
    public string Descricao { get; private set; }
}

var lstData = new List<ObjetoTeste>
{
    new ObjetoTeste(1, "Valor 1"),
    new ObjetoTeste(2, "Valor 2"),
    new ObjetoTeste(3, "Valor 3"),
    new ObjetoTeste(4, "Valor 4")
};

cboComboBox1.DataSource = null;
cboComboBox1.Items.Clear();
// Utilizo um BindingSource para "bindar os dados com os itens do Combobox"
cboComboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(lstData, null);
// Aqui fala qual será o campo a ser exibido
cboComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
// Aqui fala qual campo será selecionado
cboComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Quando for pegar os dados do combobox é só utilizar a propriedade SelectedValue do mesmo:

```
int intCodigoSelecionado = (int) cboComboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem pelo que percebi da pergunta você quer um código assim

```
string escolha;

if (comboBox1.Text == "Limitado")
{
    escolha = "L";
}    
else if (comboBox1.Text == "Total")
{
    escolha = "F";
}
```

Depois é só usar a variável escolha quando for inserido na base de dados.